# Quick way to show the full catalog in front-end layered navigation grid

Tags: catalog, layered-navigation

In the base layout/catalog.xml, there's the 'catalog_category_layered' handle:

```
<catalog_category_layered translate="label">
    <label>Catalog Category (Anchor)</label>
    <reference name="left">
        <block type="catalog/layer_view" name="catalog.leftnav" after="currency" template="catalog/layer/view.phtml"/>
    </reference>
    <reference name="content">
        <block type="catalog/category_view" name="category.products" template="catalog/category/view.phtml">
            <block type="catalog/product_list" name="product_list" template="catalog/product/list.phtml">
                <!-- <action method="addReviewSummaryTemplate"><type>default</type><template>review/helper/su.phtml</template></action> -->
                <block type="catalog/product_list_toolbar" name="product_list_toolbar" template="catalog/product/list/toolbar.phtml">
                    <block type="page/html_pager" name="product_list_toolbar_pager"/>
                    <!-- The following code shows how to set your own pager increments -->
                    <!--
                        <action method="setDefaultListPerPage"><limit>4</limit></action>
                        <action method="setDefaultGridPerPage"><limit>3</limit></action>
                        <action method="addPagerLimit"><mode>list</mode><limit>2</limit></action>
                        <action method="addPagerLimit"><mode>list</mode><limit>4</limit></action>
                        <action method="addPagerLimit"><mode>list</mode><limit>6</limit></action>
                        <action method="addPagerLimit"><mode>list</mode><limit>8</limit></action>
                        <action method="addPagerLimit" translate="label"><mode>list</mode><limit>all</limit><label>All</label></action>
                        <action method="addPagerLimit"><mode>grid</mode><limit>3</limit></action>
                        <action method="addPagerLimit"><mode>grid</mode><limit>6</limit></action>
                        <action method="addPagerLimit"><mode>grid</mode><limit>9</limit></action>
                        <action method="addPagerLimit" translate="label"><mode>grid</mode><limit>all</limit><label>All</label></action>
                    -->
                </block>
                <action method="addColumnCountLayoutDepend"><layout>empty</layout><count>6</count></action>
                <action method="addColumnCountLayoutDepend"><layout>one_column</layout><count>5</count></action>
                <action method="addColumnCountLayoutDepend"><layout>two_columns_left</layout><count>4</count></action>
                <action method="addColumnCountLayoutDepend"><layout>two_columns_right</layout><count>4</count></action>
                <action method="addColumnCountLayoutDepend"><layout>three_columns</layout><count>3</count></action>
                <action method="setToolbarBlockName"><name>product_list_toolbar</name></action>
            </block>
        </block>
    </reference>
</catalog_category_layered>
```

which eventually filters the product list by category id. Is there a simple way to avoid filtering by category, and list all the products in the store catalog, i.e, a product collection without any filters (except, optionally, store id)?

Comment: Please explain in detail.

Comment: "list all the products in the store catalog?" means explain in detail.

Comment: Basically you want to hide layered navigation?

Comment: No. Quite the opposite. I want a layered navigation page for the entire catalog.

Comment: that is quite customization task and challenging task because you have to override the magento Inbuilt functionality. so

Comment: I could perhaps add a block in app/code/local/mynamespace/mymodule/Block inheriting from catalog/product_list and overload a method. This is what I'm trying now, but I'm getting SQL errors so far...

Comment: hmm you have to override your catalog blocks, controllers and model. better you can take your senior help

Comment: Your offensive remark is very much appreciated. Regardless, I'm pretty sure this will require overloading only block/s and maybe one controller.

Comment: just focus of your logic and implement that you got your solution.

Comment: Huh? What did you just write there?

Comment: implement this functionality you got success...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would say just add a new category as child of your `Store Root Category`, then add everything to this.

If you then flag this category as anchor, you will see all the products.

I think you will then have a problem with the menus, but if you ask me, it is easier to fix, then implement your own layered navigation.

Comment: Sounds good. Maybe I'll add an observer for new products and automatically add to that category as well. What do you say?

Comment: This is a great alternative. If you want to have a category filter in your layered navigation, you might need to copy the categories as well :-/